# How to reference sass styles of is-invalid onto a custom class?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

Within Bootstrap, there is a class we can use called `is-invalid`.  I'm using a separate validation tool that adds the class `input-validation-error` onto my elements where the issue is invalid. **I cannot change that name**.  Nor do I want to duplicate styling that `is-invalid` already provides.

Is there a way from SASS, that I can borrow the mixin or color schemes of `is-invalid` and apply them to my custom class called `input-validation-error`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can simply use @extend...

```
.input-validation-error {
   @extend .is-invalid;
}
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/IBJbBsznKP

---

Related: [How to extend existing SASS bootstrap grid classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38900098/how-to-extend-existing-sass-bootstrap-grid-classes)

Comment: You are the man @Zim.  I totally forgot about extend.  Thanks for the example too!

Comment: My apologies I ran into an issue...I realized that I'm not on an npm webpack project, but instead I am using Bootstrap 4 as a CDN for the given project.  Is there anyway I can extend .is-invalid from a remote location?  or is that not possible?

Comment: No, not possible since SASS must be compiled on the server first.

Comment: Understood.  Thanks

Comment: Notice: you have to import the scss file not the css. In my structure @import "../lib/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";. First i included the css file and got an error "Incompatible units: 'rem' and 'em'." when compiling.